# Any proper way to report the writeErrors after bulk_write is executed in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

After bulk_write operation is performed in mongodb, the BulkWriteError prints the "Duplicate Key Error" (which I am expecting) in the console in the below format.

```
{'nModified': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'writeErrors': 
[{u'index': 8, u'code': 11000, u'errmsg': u'E11000 duplicate key error 
index: csgdb_new1_5L_master.buckets.$name_1 dup key: { : "bucket19" }', 
u'op': {u'status': u'CREATED', u'owner': u'805c0f53803f91f56596c379c0', 
u'_id': {u'bucket_id': 1000009, u'system_id': u'22e08083-c09f-4465- 
99e3-02f7138ff58e'}, u'creation_time': Timestamp(1544509097, 0), 
u'name': u'bucket19'}}, {u'index': 9, u'code': 11000, u'errmsg': 
u'E11000 duplicate key error index: 
csgdb_new1_5L_master.buckets.$name_1 dup key: { : "bucket20" }', u'op': 
{u'status': u'CREATED', u'owner': u'805c0f53803f91f56596c379c0', 
u'_id': {u'bucket_id': 1000013, u'system_id': u'22e08083-c09f-4465- 
99e3-02f7138ff58e'}, u'creation_time': Timestamp(1544509118, 0), 
u'name': u'bucket20'}}, {u'index': 33, u'code': 11000, u'errmsg': 
u'E11000 duplicate key error index: 
csgdb_new1_5L_master.buckets.$name_1 dup key: { : "bucket22" }', u'op': 
{u'status': u'CREATED', u'owner': u'805c0f53803f91f56596c379c0', 
u'_id': {u'bucket_id': 1000011, u'system_id': u'22e08083-c09f-4465- 
99e3-02f7138ff58e'}, u'creation_time': Timestamp(1544509105, 0), 
u'name': u'bucket22'}}], 'upserted': [], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 
'nRemoved': 0, 'nInserted': 511154}
```

Is there any proper way to create a report for this Duplicate Key error?
 Let say I want to capture the error in CSV format, possible?

Answer (score 0):

** This is a hint to solution **

From the `error` object you can get `writeErrors` which is an array `[]`.

If the above message was actually your error object then -

```
const writeErrors = error.writeErrors;
```

Now you can do a for loop on the `writeErrors` and extract the data. :)